# How to link two expressions with Any to formulate an EF Core query

Tags: c#, expression-trees, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to formulate an Expression for a condition of an EF Core query. What I have so far is an expression that transforms my query result type to an `IEnumerable` and a predicate for the type of the `IEnumerable` that transforms it into a `bool`. Now I want to link them with an Any condition. What I was trying so far is this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TIn, bool>> Any<TIn, T>(
        Expression<Func<TIn, IEnumerable<T>>> valueFunction,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var call = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Any), new[] { typeof(T) }, value, predicate);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, bool>>(call);
}
```

This throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : No generic method 'Any' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

I would imagine that this happens because I try to use the `Expression` of the `Func` and not a `ParameterExpression` to call the `Any` method.

So my question is, is it even possible to do that and if yes how? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TIn, bool>> Any<TIn, T>(
           Expression<Func<TIn, IEnumerable<T>>> valueFunction,
           Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
        .Where(mi => mi.Name =="Any" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .Single()
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
    var call = Expression.Call(method, valueFunction.Body, predicate);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, bool>>(call, valueFunction.Parameters);
}
```

So you had few issues here. First of all your selector expression returns `IEnumerable` so you need to get method from `Enumerable` (if you will need to handle `IQueryable`'s a little more work will be needed, like checking `valueFunction.Body.Type` to implement `IQueryable`). Then you need to select correct method and since `Any` is generic one - you need to set specific type to the type parameters, thus creating a MethodInfo object that represents a particular constructed method (`MakeGenericMethod`). And lastly use `valueFunction.Body` for one of the `Call` arguments.

Comment: Thank You. As the condition should be evaluated on the database it is necessary to get the Any method from Queryable, however the body of the valueFunction is already defined yo return IQueryable, so I just needed to change the Expression generic.